# Json Webservice Call in Apex Salesforce

Tags: json, salesforce, apex

Can anyone share an end to end example for making a JSON webservice Call Through Apex ( Visual Force Pages and Controllers ) in Salesforce .
Pretty Much like we do in HTML5 ,Jquery by Ajax !

Comment: For RestFul Webservices and SOAP Webservices.

Answer (score 2):

There are examples right in the documentation of calling REST web services.

From [HTTP Classes](https://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_classes_restful_http.htm):

```
public class HttpCalloutSample {

// Pass in the endpoint to be used using the string url
  public String getContent(String url) {

// Instantiate a new http object
    Http h = new Http();

// Instantiate a new HTTP request, specify the method (GET) as well as the endpoint
    HttpRequest req = new HttpRequest();
    req.setEndpoint(url);
    req.setMethod('GET');

// Send the request, and return a response
    HttpResponse res = h.send(req);
    return res.getBody();
  }
}
```

You can change the method to one of:

> GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, TRACE, CONNECT, HEAD, and OPTIONS

A more complete example is available at [HTTP (RESTful) Services](https://developer.salesforce.com/page/Apex_Web_Services_and_Callouts#HTTP_.28RESTful.29_Services)

There is also support for [JSON deserialization](https://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_methods_system_json_overview.htm#kanchor774).

Don't forget to use the [Remote Site Settings](https://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_callouts_remote_site_settings.htm) to open up access to the target domain.

For a SOAP web service you can [define Apex classes from a WSDL](https://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_callouts_wsdl2apex.htm).